# How do i handle this calender Scenrio in the Selenium Date Picker

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing

In this code i want to navigate to the year 2022 and select July and result that ouput in the console but the issue is that in the else if condition when checking
when this particular condition is encounted where the year is 2022 and the month is december it is passing and it is navigating to next Button which is January 2023 so the loop keeps on running and i cannot get my desired result

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;

public class DatePicker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5000));

        driver.get("https://seleniumpractise.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-handle-calendar-in-selenium.html");

        driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();

        String desiredMonth = "July";
        String desiredYear = "2022";

        while (true) {
            String year1 = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")).getText();
            String month1 = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-month")).getText();

            if (year1.equals(desiredYear) && month1.equalsIgnoreCase(desiredMonth)) {
                System.out.println("Desired date reached: the year is " + year1 + " and the month is " + month1);
                break;
            } else if (year1.equals(desiredYear) && month1.compareTo(desiredMonth) < 0) {
                driver.findElement(By.className("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e")).click();
            } else {
                driver.findElement(By.className("ui-icon-circle-triangle-w")).click();
            }

            // Wait for the changes to take effect
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")));
        }

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is likely due to the logic in the "else if" condition. When you are checking if the year is 2022 and the month is less than "July," it doesn't account for December correctly.
Add another condition to handle this case.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;

public class DatePicker {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 
    Duration.ofSeconds(5000));

    driver.get("https://seleniumpractise.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-handle-calendar-in-selenium.html");

    driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();

    String desiredMonth = "July";
    String desiredYear = "2022";

    while (true) {
        String year1 = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")).getText();
        String month1 = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-month")).getText();

        if (year1.equals(desiredYear) && month1.equalsIgnoreCase(desiredMonth)) {
            System.out.println("Desired date reached: the year is " + year1 + " and the month is " + month1);
            break;
        } else if (year1.equals(desiredYear) && month1.compareTo(desiredMonth) < 0) {
            driver.findElement(By.className("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e")).click();
        } else if (year1.equals(desiredYear) && month1.compareTo(desiredMonth) > 0) {
            driver.findElement(By.className("ui-icon-circle-triangle-w")).click();
        } else {
            // If year1 is not equal to desiredYear, go forward
            driver.findElement(By.className("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e")).click();
        }

        // Wait for the changes to take effect
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")));
    }

    driver.quit();
 }
}
```